# Determining Gaussian Surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

When we are asked to find the electric flux due to a charge inside a 3D figure, how will we know that we have to use Gauss law or basic integration?

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's law is useful to calculate an electric field $\vec E(\vec r)$ if the symmetry of the problem allows you to make some assumptions (e.g. magnitude and/or direction of $\vec E(\vec r)$ are deducible from the symmetry of the enclosed charge distribution $\rho(\vec r)$). Splitting the surface that encloses the charge into parts might also help, e.g. the lateral section of a cylinder vs. the top or bottom areas.

So, if the charge distribution has cylindrical, spherical or any other symmetry, you choose surfaces which allow to make those assumptions about $\vec E(\vec r)$ and then you need to calculate the total charge inside the surface and the surface area - which usually is easier than solving Poisson's equation.

When there is no chance of doing this (for example, the electric field produced by a ring-like charge distribution), then you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the flux integral of the electrical field is difficult to evaluate. But as Nelson said, the advantage of symmetry that presents many charge distributions (infinite cylinder, sphere, infinite plane, etc). For magnitude field, you can choose a surface (closed) in which the electric field is a constant where the flux becomes easy the calculate, is just the product of the field and the Gauss's surface. For the field lines, you can determine the symmetrical planes of the charge distribution and then their intersection defines the field lines. But for direction is defined by the charge sign of your charge distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the net flux $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S$ is “easy” as it is just proportional to the net charge enclosed:
\begin{align}
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S= \frac{q_{encl}}{\epsilon}\, ,
\end{align}
so provided it’s easy to evaluate $q_{encl}$ no integration is needed at all, except perhaps to obtain $q_{encl}=\int \rho dV$ if the situation involves a continuous charge distribution with volume density $\rho$ (or similar situations with a surface charge density $\sigma$ or a linear charge density $\lambda$).

Of course there is no guarantee that the flux is uniform on every part of your surface, so evaluating $\int \vec E\cdot d\vec S$ over an open surface will in general require integration and could be quite complicated.

Imagine for instance a single point charge $+q$ located close to the middle of one side of a box.  The net flux $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S$ through the entire surface of the box is just $q/\epsilon_0$ but the flux through the near side will not be the same as the flux through the far side of the box.  In particular, with this non-symmetric configuration, knowledge of the net flux through the box is not useful in determining the value of $\vec E$ at a point on the box.